# Does C#'s using statement call Dispose on out parameters?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Let's say I have:

```
using(DbDataReader reader = getReader("SELECT * FROM Cmds", out DbCommand cmd))
{

}
```

where I wrote a helper method, `getReader` to obtain a `DbDataReader` and a `DbCommand`. Does the `using` statement call `Dispose` on the output parameter, `cmd` in this case? If not, is there a concise way to achieve that instead of something like:

```
DbCommand cmd = null;
try
{
    using(DbDataReader reader = getReader("select value from cmds where typeid = 2;", out cmd))
    {

    }
}
finally
{
    cmd?.Dispose();
}
```

Could I return a tuple containing both disposable objects or would that just confuse the `using` statement?

I looked at [MSDN's documentation for C#'s `using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) but it did not mention anything about `out` parameters obtained in the expression.

Comment: I doubt it does care about such variables. It would be undesirable side-effect in many cases. How could you tell apart?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does the using statement call Dispose on the output parameter, `cmd` in this case?

No, it does not. It only calls `Dispose` on the instance being created/assigned/passed directly inside the `using` statement's parenthesis.

You could use multiple `using` statements and stack them though like this.

```
using(DbDataReader reader = getReader("SELECT * FROM Cmds", out DbCommand cmd))
using(cmd)
{

}
```

---

*Also notice the lack of open/closing parenthesis immediately after the 1st `using` statement which reduces the code indentation and makes it impossible to reference `cmd` after it has been disposed by the 2nd `using` statement.*

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, and this is plenty concise enough!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple IDisposable wrapper class and return that:

```
public sealed class DbData: IDisposable
{
    public DbData(DbDataReader reader, DbCommand command)
    {
        Reader  = reader;
        Command = command;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reader .Dispose();
        Command.Dispose();
    }

    public DbDataReader Reader  { get; }
    public DbCommand    Command { get; }
}
```

Then your `GetReader()` would return a `DbData`:

```
public DbData GetReader(string sql)
{
    DbDataReader reader  = ...;
    DbCommand    command = ...;

    return new DbData(reader, command);
}
```

Then you could use that with a `using`.

```
using (var result = GetReader("SELECT * FROM Cmds"))
{
    // Do something with result.Command and result.Reader
}
```